# PyCharm running slow performing "update usage to reflect signature change"

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm running slow performing "update usage to reflect signature change"

When I change the name of a function in my project file and run "update usage to reflect signature change" sometimes it takes very long time also 2 hours.

I checked and looks like it happens when the usage of the function is more than 60.
Also looks like when inside the function there is an operation on files located in directory containing dozen of thousands of files(NB: this directory is excluded from indexing)

I'm newest to use PyCharm and I found it very confortable, before I was using Atom.

Considering my computer is not the topgun as well.
Is anyone suggesting me how can I improve this action or is it a bug?
Nobody can wait 2 hours every name modification on a function, is n't it?

I do faster using "Find Usages" and replace manually the new name in every files found (some minutes instead of hours).
I feel this solution a little bit crazy.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: after a system crash and after the last system updates and pycharm updates everything is running with reasonable timeline. Maybe that it was need only a good upgrade